# Kubernetes: route traffic to a subnet via a pod (accesing management VPN clients from pods)

Tags: kubernetes, wireguard, calico

Given two pods deployed on different nodes:

1. **myapp** pod deployed on apps node
2. **wireguard** pod deployed on vpn node, using a subnet like 172.16.30.0/16

I need **myapp** to be able to be able to route traffic to the **wireguard** peers (VPN clients) having IPs in the subnet 172.16.30.0/16, the traffic is mostly ICMP probes, SSH and iperf tests, the VPN clients are network devices managed via an application called [OpenWISP](https://openwisp.org/).

I already enabled IP forwarding on the **wireguard** pode and VPN node, now I need to understand: how do I set up routes in a way that plays nicely with the Kubernetes networking model?

That is, I want to instruct the **myapp** pods to send traffic for the subnet used by wireguard (172.16.30.0/16) to the **wireguard** container so that the traffic is routed to the VPN clients.

Thanks in advance to anyone who will help.

Comment: Should the clients be on the same subnet? This seems a bit odd, because WireGuard is a layer3 VPN, which means you cannot bridge both VPN clients and the pods together, but rather you need to route the traffic between them.